# Best Practice -- Create Bootstrap template with 3 columns -- Left & Right Sidebars

Tags: javascript, php, css, twitter-bootstrap, templates

I want an easy way to create a three column bootstrap template which will have (1) left sidebar, (2) middle/main content area and (3) right sidebar.

While it is not difficult for me to create 3 bootstrap columns in a single page, my problem is how to include same right and left sidebars in every page.

I know I can create 3 columns in a single page like this

```
<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<div class = " col-lg-3"> Left column</div>
<div class = "col-lg-6"> Main/Middle column </div>
<div class = col-lg-3" Right column </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Also, I know I can do something like this on every page
E.g index.php

```
<?php include 'left_sidebar.php' ?>

<div class = "container">
<div class = "row">
<div class = "col-lg-12"> Middle/main content area</div>
</div>
</div>

<?php include 'right_sidebar.php' ?>
```

Where left_sidebar.php and right_sidebar.php contains one column each.

However, that would require me to write some CSS and some JS to hold the sidebars in their respective right and left positions.

I would prefer to use core Bootstrap for all the three column without writing extra CSS or JS. Any help, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place your php includes inside your col-3 divs.

```
<div class = "container">
 <div class = "row">
  <div class = " col-lg-3"> 
   <?php include 'left_sidebar.php' ?>
  </div>
  <div class = "col-lg-6"> 
    Main/Middle column
  </div>
  <div class = col-lg-3">
  <?php include 'right_sidebar.php' ?>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh wow, i'm smiling, Just why the hell I couldn't figure this out? Thanks for helping me out @James

Comment: No worries, glad it helped :)